# Remove characters after hyphen and reformat string

Tags: php, regex

Just looking for the most streamlined approach.

I need to take a string formatted like this and remove the "-D2"
12345678-D2

then append the "9-" to the beginning of the string

9-12345678

Comment: `echo "9-".(int)"12345678-D2";`

Comment: @AbraCadaver, wont work for anything with leading 0s

Comment: Find `^([^-]+).*` replace with `9-$1`?

Comment: Use `preg_match('/^([0-9]+).+$/', $string, $m );` and you'll get the matching number in array $m

Comment: use substr like this `$var=substr('Your string',7)` ` $tar = "9 - var - D2"`; Point to note i am using seven as substr start counting the string from zero, so 7 going to count 8, read the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [php fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be447a24a8ef07d8343c22d736f5a069b3995843) , does what you want above.

```
$str = "12345678-D2"; //example string

$num = explode("-",$str);
$formatted = "9-".$num[0];
print_r($formatted);

//output is 9-12345678
```

Comment: @Sylvester, perfect.

Comment: thank you @Johanna, if this solves your issue then please mark the answer as solved :)